# @EntityListeners Annotation Causes TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy Error

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-jpa

I have a JPA entity that looks something like this.  Note the `@EntityListeners` annotation:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

@XmlRootElement
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners( { AuditingEntityListener.class } )
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable
{
    //body
}
```

I'm using Hibernate as the JPA provider.

I use Spring's `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` to create the JPA `EntityManager`.  I use the `setPersistenceUnitPostProcessors` method to set a `PersistenceUnitPostProcessor` instance that registers the entity classes in the `postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo` method.  (I know it's not Spring Boot, but that's a topic for another time).

After setting a `DataSource` and other properties on the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, calling the `afterPropertiesSet` method throws this exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
    at java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(AnnotatedElement.java:258)
    at java.lang.Class.isAnnotationPresent(Class.java:3425)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaAnnotationReader.isAnnotationPresent(JavaAnnotationReader.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXAnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(JavaXAnnotatedElement.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.categorizeAnnotatedClass(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
```

I commented out `@EntityListeners( { AuditingEntityListener.class } )` annotation on the entity class listed above.

After that, the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`'s `afterPropertiesSet()` method did *not* throw an error, and it produced a usable `EntityManager` instance (I was able to use it to do a basic select of an entity).  So, at least I know that the rest of the setup works correctly.

Can anybody tell me *why* I'm getting the error when using the `@EntityListeners` annotation, and how I can fix it?  As far as I can tell it's in the runtime classpath (the `javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar` file is in the webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory) and so is the `AuditingEntityListener` class (in the `spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar` file).

If it's helpful, these are the Gradle entries I'm using to get the dependencies:

```
compile "org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.7.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.7.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.7.RELEASE"

compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.11.6.RELEASE"
compile "javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final"
```

What can I do to get rid of the error when using the `@EntityListeners` annotation?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some more testing.  I found that this annotation did *not* produce an error:

```
@EntityListeners( { } )
```

So the `AuditingEntityListener` appeared to be the culprit.

More web searching turned up [this issue in Spring](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-367).  It mentioned the `spring-aspects`project as being necessary for the runtime code weaving of `AuditingEntityListener`, so I added this to my Gradle build file:

```
compile "org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.3.10.RELEASE"
```

After a rebuild and redeploy the problem went away!  Yay!